# How to make php mvc dynamic url

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I am using mvc structure. When I open a category from the database, I want to convert it to a page. for example: "localhost/videos" ie "localhost/categoryname". but I couldn't figure out how to write the htacess and php code. I looked everywhere and searched a lot, but I could not find such an example anywhere.
what exactly i found
I don't want "localhost/product/pagename" to be that way, please don't give a direct minus. Those who research this, like me, should see and learn.

Note: I don't want existing controls and views to be affected.

Comment: this is quite a broad question, have you tried anything at all? There are different ways to build a routing system, but in general you will need to parse the url in some kind of `front controller` and then direct it to where you want it to go.  Probably via  a `config` or `yml` file which works as a route registry and then checks for parameters/route patterns and directs to the correct controller.  It's not super simple, but it is doable (I'm on the 4th or 5th iteration of mine).  But really, while it's good as a learning exercise, it's really reinventing the wheel and you might prefer...

Comment: ... to use something that already exists

Comment: I did not understand anything you said